# create deployment and pods via openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to run the command "**oc apply -f basic-ocp-demo.yaml**" in order to **create services and deployment** in my **openshift**, but I get an error regarding "**unable to decode "basic-ocp-demo.yaml ": no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "v1beta1 "**

**My file look like :**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx-app
    type: front-end
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30012
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: v1beta1 
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
    type: front-end
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
      type: front-end
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-app
        type: front-end
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-container
          image: nginx:latest
```

**oc apply command output:**

```
[root@localhost openshift]# oc apply -f basic-ocp-demo.yaml 
service "nginx-service" created
error: unable to decode "basic-ocp-demo.yaml": no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "v1beta1"
```

Seems that my service nginx was created but the Deployment kind has no registration for version "**v1bet1**", I tried to put many other version but the same problem:

I've tried with "**apps/v1**", the same issue:

```
error: unable to decode "basic-ocp-demo.yaml": no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1"
```

I've made a curl where can be seen all the apis available but I don't know what to choose from that list for my Deployment Kind.

Here is my apis list : https://92.42.107.195:8443/apis

Answer (score 3):

It would appear you are running an extremely old version of OpenShift/Kubernetes. So all you have available is `apps/v1alpha1`. You should upgrade ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the command `oc api-resources` to list all the resources and use the mentioned version API version from the list for the deployment.

Comment: I will upgrade the openshift to 3.11, Thank you

Comment: I've upgraded to 3.11 and now it's work like a charm. Thank you guys